# I wanted to relation two tables when this message appeared to me

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, multiple-columns, relation

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column** 'school_class_names.schoolClassName_id' in 'where clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: `` select * from `school_class_names` where `school_class_names`.`schoolClassName_id` = 1 limit 1 ``)

I'm new to the Laravel world and I don't know exactly what it means.

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE school_class_names;` and look for actual column name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.